# Why does current in this circuit disappear instantly

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductor

[image]

In this circuit initial current of 3ampere is given in both inductors  (just before closing of switch), And after closing   the switch, I calculated current in the circuit by laplace transform and it turns out that current will be zero, so where does all the initial currents disappear?
Or my calculation is wrong and some current will flow after closing the switch?
Here is my solution -
[image]

Comment: If the switch is open, how can there be 3A in each inductor?

Comment: Where do the 2 12V sources come from? They are not present in your circuit before opening the switch.

Comment: 12 volt comes in laplace transform i.e multiple of inductance and initial current

Comment: Let's say these two inductors  connected to some other circuits and at the instant when current across both the inductors become 3, we open those circuits and close this switch ( In image), That's how how? 3A comes from

Comment: In the first picture +3A is flowing in both inductors, **but against each other**. either one arrow should be reversed or equivalently one current should be designated as -3A. If not, it doesn't seem surprising that two inductors of equal *strength* (4H) with opposing currents cancel each other out.

Comment: Yeah, but that's my question where does all the energy goes if net current become zero instantly, how is that possible

Comment: The sudden drop in current will lead to infinitely large voltage being developed inside each inductor. In a practical circuit, it may lead to arcing. In theory, we have ill defined mathematical equations (?). Imagine another example where an inductor, a closed switch and a voltage source are connected in a loop. What happens when the switch is opened instantaneously after some current has built up ? Where does the energy go ?

Comment: If you assume that the current changes **instantly** (in zero time) then you can't analyze the circuit mathematically. That is, you can't calculate what happens to the energy because your circuit requires an infinite voltage and the equations break down. In a real circuit, the energy will probably be lost setting the switch on fire.